# Which pointer value is the max for a malloc call

Tags: c, malloc

Fairly simple question regarding malloc. What is the max that I can set within the allocated area. For instance:

```
char *buffer;
buffer = malloc(20);
buffer[19] = 'a'; //Is this the highest spot I can set?
buffer[20] = 'a'; //Or is this the highest spot I can set?
free(buffer);
```

Comment: work it out yourself with the simple case of malloc(1)

Comment: With a malloc(1), can I only set buffer[0] = 'a' or can I also set buffer[1]  = 'a'?

Comment: just remember in C, index is 0 based. so the index to the first element is 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrasing of your question is a bit off.  You mean "what is the maximum index I can use for an allocated block of memory".  The answer is the same as for arrays.

- If you are reading or writing the memory, you may safely use indices between (and including) 0 and one less than the size of the block (in your case, that means index 19).  All up, that means you can access the 20 values that you asked for.
- If you are simply obtaining the pointer for comparison with other pointers inside the same block (*and you are not going to read or write to it*), you may additionally obtain the pointer one-past-the-end (in your case that means index 20).

To clarify these things with examples:

1. Yes, `buffer[19] = 'a';` is the very last value you may access in a read or write capacity.  Don't forget that if you want to store a string in this memory, and hand it to functions that expect a null-terminated string, this slot is your last chance to put that value of `'\0'`.
2. You are allowed to access `buffer[20]` in the following manner:

   ```
   char *p;
   for( p = &buffer[0]; p != &buffer[20]; ++p )
   {
       putc( *p, stdout );
   }
   ```

   This is useful because of the way we tend to iterate over memory and store sizes.  It would make our code quite less readable if we had to subtract 1 all over the place.

   Oh, and it gives you the neat trick:

   ```
   size_t buf_size = 20;
   char *buffer = malloc(buf_size);
   char *start = buffer;
   char *end = buffer + buf_size; 
   size_t oops_i_forgot_the_size = end - start;
   ```

Comment: Awesome answer +1. You might choose to add why on might want an instance of the (non dereferenceable) pointer to after the end of the memory.

Comment: Okay, I added a simple example, but haven't provided an exhaustive list of other patterns that exploit this behaviour.

Comment: Shouldn't `oops_i_forgot_the_size` be type `ptrdiff_t`?

Answer (score 2):

`malloc(x)` will allocate `x` bytes.

So by accessing `buffer[0]` you access the first byte, by accessing `buffer[1]` you access the second.

e.g

```
char * buffer = (char *) malloc(1);
buffer[0] = 0; // legal
buffer[1] = 0; // illegal
```